# C# retrieve report from "SAP Crystal Server"

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-server

I have installed SAP Crystal Server on a Windows 2012 Server machine. The installation looks fine.  I can run the Central Management Console and everything appears to be up and running.

I have a Windows application running on my local machine and all I want to do is run a report.

```
        myRCDoc = new ReportClientDocument();
        myRCDoc.ReportAppServer = _server;

        object path = reportName;
        myRCDoc.Open(ref path, 0);
```

I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Billings.exe
>
> Additional information: Failed to connect to server "ENTBSQ01".

How do I make the server reachable from my windows code?

Comment: Have you tried the code locally in the server, to rule out firewall or network connectivity issues?